# Is it possible to make iCloud Photo library read only on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, photos

I would like to give my daughter access to my complete iCloud library on her iPad. The only problem I see is that she might accidentally deleting Photos. Is there any kind of access restriction would make this scenario safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photos has a "Recently Deleted" album. Whenever a photo is deleted, it goes into that album, where you have 30 days to restore it before it disappears forever. If you trust your daughter to not delete photos from the main library and then discover that album and manually delete the photos, all you'll have to do is check the Recently Deleted album regularly and you'll be fine!